# Add link to display original question for answers in the Suggested Edits review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Whenever I'm reviewing a Suggested Edit in an answer, it feels like the piece of text in my front has close to no context besides the Question's title displayed at the top.

Of course, for many edits it is just a matter of formatting or grammar fixes, but for others it is necessary to have more context to evaluate the edit properly.

I'm aware that I can just middle-click the question title and open the thread in a new tab to read the question properly, but this simply slows down the reviewing process and may lead to more inaccurate reviews as many reviewers do not open a new page to assimilate the context before pressing those shiny Approve and Reject buttons.

And I can back-up this, this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1881549) promptly had 3 rejects - most likely because it *looks* like an attempt from someone to reply/comment on the post, but in fact it is from the question's OP himself fixing some invalid syntax and seemingly wrong logic in the answer that he has accepted for showing a correct approach.

Without further ado, may we have a small excerpt of the question alongside the answer?

I'm not very good with UX but my initial idea would be a small text excerpt from the question below answers' suggested edits, excerpt which upon being clicked expands to a full question text with question score and OP. Would something like this be possibly implemented in the future?

IMHO this would aid the review process, making it faster and with less inaccuracies.

---

**Update:** Also, I believe a feature similar to this already exists. The answers in the "Review Low Quality Posts" queue do have the original question below them, therefore it would be viable to re-utilize this existing feature and hopefully not waste too much development time.

---

**Update 2:** I'll start listing more examples that I get too see to better illustrate the issue. As I can only review 20 edits a day, I may not get these issues too often, but let's see if the problem persists for while I keep reviewing the suggested edits.

- [#1881549](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1881549) - The aforementioned edit. Rejected due to no context/OP knowledge.
- [#1889180](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1889180) - Rejected due to the lack of Answer's comments context.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're screen is a jumbo-tron, I don't think there is a need for the question to clutter up the edit. The focus is on the content being edited. If it's the tags, then those are well highlighted. I think the review process should be quick and easy without more unnecessary information distracting the reviewer.

However, at times it may be necessary to review the original post and in that case, just opening it in a new window doesn't seem *that* tedious.

Comment: The Review Low Quality Posts queue has such a feature and IMHO it does help more than clutter. My initial idea to display just a excerpt (and then possibly load the rest of the question data through Ajax when requested) wouldn't clutter nor put too much extra HTTP request bytes until requested. Though I agree that these should be fast and easy, IMO the Suggested Edits queue does lack some context for the answers and having to open a new window loading an entire page just to check the question does not seem like the optimal UX which the rest of SO provides.